# Prove if the set of complex numbers of absolute value 1 is a subgroup of nonzero complex numbers

Tags: group-theory

**GIVEN:** Let $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup> denotes the group of complex numbers where each complex number can be presented as *z=a+ib*. Denote $\mathcal{U}$ the set of complex number of absolute value 1, $\mathcal{P}$ will denote the positive reals.

---

**QUESTION:** Prove that U is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup>. Prove that P is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup>. Are $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ normal subgroups of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup> ? Why or why not?? Please explain clearly!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes if you edit the question to show how far you got and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm quite sure by $\mathbb{C}^*$ you mean the non-zero complex numbers and the group structure is determined by the product. You should mention this in your post. Anyway, let $z_1,z_2$ be two complex numbers such that $|z_i|=1$, what can you say about $|z_1z_2|$ and what is $|z_1^{-1}|$? Also, normal groups come for free if your parent group is commutative.

Comment: Please show us your effort!  I am responding to your last three word sentence.  Why should we meet you halfway, when you're not willing to add context: what you're tried? the criteria you know that defines a subgroup of a group?, etc.  And, you've asked too many questions (three), all stated as orders to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $U$ is a subgorup of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup> it has to satisfy

1. **Closure**

   Let $(a+bi)$, $(c+di)$ $\in U$. Then
   $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i=$
   $(ac-bd)^2 +(ad+bc)^2=a^2c^2-2acbd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+2abcd=$
   $a^2(c^2+d^2)+b^2(c^2+d^2)=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$
2. **Inverse**

   $\frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}=a-bi$ as $a^2+b^2=1$

Hence $\frac{1}{a+bi}=(a+bi)^{-1}\in U$ and $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup>

*Prove the same for $P$ using the same criteria*

To show that they are normal you can show that the complex multiplication and positive reals multiplicative and they are subgroups of  $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup> under multiplication. But since the group is commutative it means that the group is Abelian and all the subgroups of an abelian group are normal, therefore $U$ and $P$ are normal subgroups of $\mathbb{C}$<sup>x</sup>.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful!